# How to get a variable from scriplet in tag file

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, tagfile

These are my first steps in tag file. Maybe this question is very simple. But I can't solve it.

I have the following tag file

```
<% 
Foo foo=new Foo();
%>
<jsp:include page="${foo.getFileName()}"/>
```

It seems to me that jasper doesn't see foo variable. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the expression language `${...}` your variable must be accessible in one of the `PageContext, Request, Session, Application...` scopes.

In order to make your code work, you must change it to:

```
<% 
Foo foo=new Foo();
pageContext.setAttribute("foo", foo);
%>
<jsp:include page="${foo.getFileName()}"/>
```

If you are using a tag file, then prefer maybe `jspContext` instead of `pageContext`:

```
  <% 
    Foo foo=new Foo();
    jspContext.setAttribute("foo", foo);
    %>
    <jsp:include page="${foo.getFileName()}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. But when I use pagecontext i got the following:                                             .org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 11 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/tags/insertArea.tag
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable pageContext

Comment: I updated the post. Looking at you exception, it seems that your code is running in a tag file

Answer (score 0):

${some variable name} takes variable name from a scope e.g. request/session/application.

But your foo object has not been set in any scopes.

just for a try, `use session.setAttribute("foo", foo)` or `pageContext.setAttribute(...)` **inside the scriptlet** and try.

Now just try to understand the scopes and which scope better fits in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Here, scrptlet `foo` is not recognized at `<jsp:include/>` `EL`

Use `<jsp:useBean/>` action to use at `<jsp:include/>` as EL

```
 <jsp:useBean id="foo"  class="packeage.Foo"  scope="page"/>
 <jsp:include page="${foo.fileName}"/>
```